# jQuery set element li data from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

If I have a list:

```
<div class="item active ui-sortable">
  <li class="player ui-droppable" data-name="Kev" data-pick-id="534dd2424b65762a89020000">
    Teddy Bridgewater
    <div class="pull-right" id="player-badges">
      <span id="points-holder">
        10
      </span>
      <span class="remove-player player-badge">
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="player pick-blank ui-droppable" data-name="" data-pick-id="534dd2424b65762a89030000">
    EMPTY
    <div class="pull-right" id="player-badges">
      <span id="points-holder">
        7
      </span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="player ui-droppable" data-name="kevin" data-pick-id="534dd2424b65762a89040000">
    kevin
    <div class="pull-right" id="player-badges">
      <span id="points-holder">
        5
      </span>
      <span class="remove-player player-badge">
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```

And I'm making an array of `data-pick-id`, how would I then rewrite this list based on the array `["534dd2424b65762a89020000", "534dd2424b65762a89030000", "534dd2424b65762a89040000"]`?

Context: I'm using jquery-sortable and want to preserve the dom structure of the `data-pick-id` *only*. That way I can change all the contents and update to server while retaining the actual dom position by ID.

Again, all I want to do is loop through and write that array to each `data-pick-id`. Would a loop be the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) would suffice:

```
var ids = [1, 2, 3];

$('.player').each(function(i) {
    $(this).data('pick-id', ids[i]);
});
```

*You may wish to make the selector more explicit.*

Comment: For some reason this isn't working for me...I'll debug.

Comment: You have to use `$(this).attr('data-pick-id', ids[i])`...for some reason you can't set data??

Comment: @KevinBrown Oops, forgot to add the `$()` wrapper ;-)